# Passing `id` to `useCallback` when using `react-autosave`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autosave

In the [README of react-autosave](https://github.com/jollyjerr/react-autosave), it's mentioned I should use `useCallback` but I'm not sure how to pass `id` to it as I need that in the mutation.

`id` & `text` is everchanging in my case.

```
const updateDraft = useCallback(
    (newText: string) => {
      console.log('updateDraft')
      console.log({ id: snap.doc.id, text: newText })
      updateDocs({ id: snap.doc.id, text: newText })
      toggleIsSaved(true)
    },
    [snap.doc.id]
  )

  useAutosave({
    data: snap.doc.text,
    onSave: updateDraft,
  })
```

I am using `valtio` as a global state manager. That's where the `snap.doc.id` is coming from. But everytime, the 1st `snap.doc.id` gets passed because of `useCallback` as the same function is used so every time it mutates the same row as `snap.doc.id` remains the same.

Complete reproduction on branch `react-autosave` → https://github.com/deadcoder0904/docs-autosync/tree/react-autosave

Comment: If `snap.doc.id` changes then `updateDraft` will use the latest id as it's added as a dependency. If that's not the case, `snap.doc.id` may not be updating properly.

Comment: @RameshReddy it is updating properly. i can see it in the `console.log` i've added just above & in the redux devtools as well but the database gets updated on the same value.

Comment: what does updateDocs do?

Comment: it's a mutation that has been called by `react-query`. it updates the database. see [this line of code](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/docs-autosync/blob/3c92e973eba9e4683dd1444e7d3641fed7d1510d/components/Writer.tsx#L14)

Comment: Is it possible to check the id that's being sent to the backend before updating the database? Is it always receiving the same id?

Comment: @RameshReddy yes i can check which id is being sent to the backend. the problem is `react-autosave` gets called 5 seconds later & if i create new docs before it gets sent, then i get the same text sent to 2 different ids. i guess i solved the question using `[snap.doc.id]` in `useCallback` but facing this problem now. I can confirm that `[snap.doc.id]` solved the same `id` problem

Comment: @RameshReddy i think i found the solution as entered below. it works for now but i'll have to do some real-world testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed the complete `doc` to it & destructured it in `useCallback` like:

```
const updateDraft = useCallback(
    ({ id, text }: Doc) => {
      if (id !== '') {
        updateDocs({ id, text })
      }
      toggleIsSaved(true)
    },
    [snap.doc.id]
  )

  useAutosave({
    data: snap.doc,
    onSave: updateDraft,
  })
```

Turns out, this works perfectly fine.